# How to pass "event" to an object literal, jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.someClass', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Some code...
});
```

I would like to rewrite this as:

```
blah = {
    init: function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Some code...
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '.someClass', blah.init);
```

But how do I pass the e variable to the object?

Comment: Your object literal is totally messed up. Just use a normal function.

Comment: `init: function(e) { ... }`

Comment: When should I use an object literal and when should I use a normal function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `init` as a function :

```
blah = {
    init: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Some code...
    }     
}
```

Comment: do I need to also do something like blah.init(e) when calling it?

Comment: No, just give the function as callback just like you did

Comment: Since you are using jQuery to setup the click event it will pass the event to your function for you. See http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler

Comment: It is just the same for plain Javascript - (without jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
blah = {
    init: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Some code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use an object literal's function as an event handler's callback, you must set the parameters of the literal's function equal to the parameters which the event callback requires, if you wish to access them.

Like so:

```
var blah = {
  init: function(e) { // we want to access the event object, so we set it as a function param
    console.log(e);
    alert('bye');
  }
}

$(document).on('click', blah.init);
```

Comment: Your code was actually incorrect. You didn't pass `e` to the literal's function as an argument, nor do you need to call the function in an anonymous callback, you can just pass it directly without invoking.